# Is it possible to use Node.js v8 on Google Kubernetes Engine after October 1, 2019?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

A month ago, I recieved a message from GPC support. It said that App Engine would stop Node.js v8 deploy support on October 1, 2019. Is it possible to continue using Node.js v8 on Google Kubernetes Engine after October 1, 2019?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems if you're creating your own docker image for K8s, I guess you can run any version of node.js

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine is based in Google Cloud Compute engine [1], therefore I believe it has a different implementation than App Engine [2]. In my opinion there will be no problems if you decide to move your workloads to GKE.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/kubernetes-engine-overview

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/

Answer (score 0):

The answers of Luca & Thrahir are correct, I will still try to expand some more.

The Node.js foundation will stop maintaining “Node 8.x” on January 2020 [1], and Google Cloud Platform’s “AppEngine” stopped deploying these apps on October 1 [2].

So if your app is deployed to AppEngine, it won’t be able to deploy if not upgraded to Node 10.

But if your app is running in an environment that you set up inside a GKE cluster, it will continue to work.

And alternatively you could also look into AppEngine’s Flexible environment for Node.JS [3].

I hope you find this information useful, and best of luck!

---

[1] https://github.com/nodejs/Release

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/release-notes#june_27_2019_2

[3] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/